# Xcode 6 not identifying some Parse 1.6.1 functions

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I just updated my Parse frameworks, which now include `Parse.framework`, `ParseUI.framework`, `ParseFacebookUtils.framework`, and `ParseCrashReporting.framework`. After importing these frameworks into my swift project and importing the following statements into my bridging file:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <ParseCrashReporting/ParseCrashReporting.h>
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
```

I am getting errors that PFImageView does not have a member named `loadInBackground()`, although loadInBackground with a completion block works. Similarly, PFObject does not have a member named '`deleteInBackground()`', althought `.delete()` works.

Is anyone else having a similar issue with the new Parse iOS SDK? Am I missing something here, or does this seem like a bug with Parse/Xcode? I've tried cleaning, building, and deleting the derived data for my project multiple times with no luck. Please let me know if there is not enough information provided. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have these methods been deprecated in the new Parse SDK update?

Answer (score 0):

Try `deleteEventually()` instead.